# How to solve this graphical function transfromation problem?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, transformation

[image]

How to solve problems like this.

I always face problem in solving function transformation related problems.

Is there any good way to solve problems like this..

Comment: Consider what this transformation does to your coordinate system, i.e what does $x'$ have to be in order to have equality $x=2x'-1$. It is useful to take some test function to see how this works out, and you will get the idea.

Comment: f(x+a) is a shift in f(x) left or right, depending on the sign of a. f(x)+b is a shift in f(x) up or down, depending on the sign of b.You can get a good idea of which graph you need by considering one x value e.g. x = 0. Locate the coordinate for y = f(0) from your original graph. Now, for your shifted graph f(2x - 1), what x value will give you f(0)? It is x = 0.5. So the graph of f(2x - 1) is that of f(x) shifted right by 0.5 and the coordinate (0, y) is shifted to (0.5, y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of it in this way

1. If the modification is in the form $y=f(x)+a$, then the graph shifts up/down by $a$.
2. If the modification is in the form $y=f(x+a)$, then the graph shifts left/right by $-a$. (Take note of the negative sign here. So for example, if we have $y=f(x-2)$, then the graph shifts to the ***right*** by 2 units.
3. If the modification is in the form $y=a \cdot f(x)$, then the graph is stretched vertically by a factor of $a$.
4. If the modification is in the form $y=f(a \cdot x)$, then the graph is stretched horizontally by a factor of $\frac{1}{a}$. (So for example if we have $y=f(2x)$, then the graph is ***"compressed"*** by half.)

Most of the questions you encounter should be a combination of the above.

All the best.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please explain me little bit by taking my question as an example?

Comment: For example, if we observe options (B) and (D), we note that the blue functions are "stretched". Thus they are in the form $y=f( \frac{1}{2} x + C)$, where C is any constant but it's irrelevant in our current discussion (assuming they are "stretched" by a factor of 2). So we immediately reject (B) and (D) as possible answers. I'm sure you will be able to figure out the answer from here!